# WCF Data Service (OData Service) working fine on local machine, but it is not working properly once it is hosted on Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure, odata, wcf-data-services

I have hosted my SQL Server database on Azure. I have created WCF Data Service with Entity model generated from that hosted database. The service works fine locally, but it is not able to access data once I published it on Azure. I am getting some firewall error saying client can not use this database. What could be the reason? Any suggestions to run my service on Azure properly?

Comment: A few questions: 1) Are you using SQL Azure or running SQL Server on a Virtual Machine?  2)  How is the WCF Data Service being hosted in Azure?  A worker role or a Virtual Machine?

Comment: Hello Grady, Answers to your questions: 1. I am using SQL Azure and not any SQL Server on virtual machine. 2. I published my .NET web project containing WCF Data Service on Azure as a web application, it has a worker role, I haven't created any virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

You should verify "allowed azure services" is "yes" on your sql azure db server: [Link Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee621782.aspx#ConnectingFromAzure)

Click Sql Databases -> Services -> *click the server with your DB on it* -> Click Configure

[image: allowed services]

Comment: It is set to 'YES'. Initially I have published my project containing OData service as a normal website,not as a worker or web role. I followed "https://venkateshnarayanan.wordpress.com/2013/05/03/creating-and-hosting-odata-service-in-azure/ this blog", and I have created new Azure cloud service project with web role. I am facing issues publishing that web role either.